# Using ModelFormMixin (base class of CreateRate) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited

Tags: django

Всем привет! Не понимаю, почему у меня не работает следующий [пример](http://Using%20ModelFormMixin%20(base%20class%20of%20CreateRate)%20without%20the%20'fields'%20attribute%20is%20prohibited.)

Я создал класс:

```
class CreateRate(CreateView):
    model = Raiting
    template_name='main/create_raiting.html'
```

И вызываю его в урлах:

```
from main.views.pages import ProfileView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^raiting/$', ProfileView.CreateRate.as_view())
]
```

И на выходе получаю следующую ошибку:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /raiting/
>   Using ModelFormMixin (base class of CreateRate) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/raiting/
>   Django Version: 1.11.17
>   Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
>   Exception Value:
>   Using ModelFormMixin (base class of CreateRate) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.
>   Exception Location: D:\django\hello\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py in get_form_class, line 129

Вроде делал все, как в документации. Моя модель:

```
class Raiting(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['Time']
        verbose_name = u'рейтинг'

    From = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='passed_Marks')
    Target = models.ForeignKey(Note, related_name='gained_Marks', verbose_name=u'Запись')
    Time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                               
    Value = models.SmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(-1), MaxValueValidator(1)] , verbose_name=u'Оценка')
```

Нашел в сети похожую [проблему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701426/using-modelformmixin-without-the-fields-attribute-is-prohibited), но там немного не так. В чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Проблема решилась принудительным объявлением fields в CreateRate. Странно, почему в исходном примере об этом ни слова...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема также решится, если в forms ты укажешь fields = '**all**', ну или что ты там хочешь делать с полями.

Comment: Да, верно. Но на тот момент я уже умел работать с формами и знал об этом. Моя задача была научиться работать со встроенными в джанго View без переопределения форм